# Find area bounded by two unequal chords and an arc in a disc

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, reference-request, area

Math people:

This question is a generalization of the one I posed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348296/find-area-bounded-by-two-chords-and-an-arc-in-a-disc .  Below is an image of a unit circle with center $O$.  $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in (0, \pi)$ and $\gamma \in (0, \min(\theta_1,\theta_2))$.  $\theta_1 = \angle ROS$, $\theta_2 = \angle POQ$, and $\gamma = \angle ROQ$.  I want to find the area of the shaded region with corners $P$, $R$, and $T$.  If $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \theta$, then the area is
 $\frac{\theta-\gamma}{2}-\tan(\frac{\theta-\gamma}{2})\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$.  I am in the middle of deriving a formula for the area for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ not necessarily equal.  I suspect that this has been done before, but I cannot find a reference.  I don't want to prove it, typeset a proof, and claim to have discovered the formula for the area if someone has done it before.  Has anyone seen this problem before, and can anyone provide a reference?

UPDATE: I derived a formula for the area. It is

$$\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}-\frac{\sin(\theta_2)}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{\gamma - \sin(\gamma)}{2}+
       \frac{2\sin^2(\frac{\gamma}{2})
      \sin(\frac{\theta_1-\gamma}{2})
             \sin(\frac{\theta_2-\gamma}{2})}
                                {\sin(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}-\gamma)}\right)$$

Unfortunately, if $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \gamma$, you get $0$ in the denominator.  But if you set $\theta_1=\theta_2=\theta$ and take the limit as $\gamma \to \theta$, you get the right value.

Of course, if anyone can locate a reference where someone has already found a formula for the area, that would also be welcome.

[image: picture of disc with two intersecting chords]

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Comment: It seems like this can be done without too much effort via calculus. Since you have the algebra-precalculus tag, I'll assume you're wanting a more elementary method. I haven't the time right now, but I'll at least see if can write out an explicit formula later.

Comment: It would be something along those lines, but maybe not exactly. I'll work on it in a few hours, but I've got homework (even though this is much more interesting :) ).

Comment: I've not forgotten, I've just been exceptionally busy. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Clayton : with the help of a friend, I have found the area without using calculus.  The proof only takes about two pages, and calculus will almost certainly not make it easier.

Comment: @Clayton : I put the answer in my question.

Comment: That is marvelous. I don't think I'll get a chance to think about it until the weekend, but I'm curious what the calculus brings to the table. I know you had an ugly answer, so I'm wondering.

Comment: @Clayton : This afternoon I found an easy proof that just requires the application of 4-5 well-known trig facts.  If you know those facts, you can almost use the "t" word for the proof.  It's almost embarrassing.  Considering this, calculus is a waste of time here.  If you're curious, I'll sketch the idea of the proof, probably within the question so the MSE system won't complain to me about holding extended discussions within comments.  Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing an article for publication I suggest you make a figure like this below. You can mention that the double integral over the region in gray is the one you claim to be. If here $D$ is the region in gray in figure below then 
$$
\mathop{\int\!\!\int}_{D\subset \mathbb{R}} dA= \mbox{ area of } D
$$
Or you can suggest your reader check the way you want the value of the area $D$.
[image]

If a figure is not convenient then make a formal description of the region $ D $ in terms of the equations $ y = mx + n $ of lines the $ \overline{SR} $ and $ \overline{QP} $ and the equation of the circle $ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $. Let's say that the set $ D $ is something like
$$
D=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R} :
\begin{array}{l}  y \leq m_{\tiny\overline{SR} }x + n_{\tiny\overline{SR} } 
\\ 
y \geq m_{\tiny\overline{PQ}}x + n_{\tiny\overline{PQ}}
\\
 x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2 \end{array} \right\} 
$$