# looking for reference for 2 trig facts

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry

Math people:

I am looking for a reference for two trigonometry facts, one of which I proved myself, and another which a random person had posted on the Web.  I have evidence to believe the second "fact".  These facts will enable me to find an embarrassingly easy solution to the problem I posed at [Find area bounded by two unequal chords and an arc in a disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356139/find-area-bounded-by-two-unequal-chords-and-an-arc-in-a-disc) .Though I have taught trig, I have never taught either of these facts.  I will accept the first answer that I see that provides a reference that it is a *book* (not a Web page) that is not too hard to find that confirms *both* facts.  I am at home and don't have access to a trig book now, and from what I have seen here there are lots of people eager to answer my questions.

(1) If $P$ and $Q$ are distinct points on a unit circle, and the arc length between them is $\theta \in (0, \pi)$, and $R$ is a third point on the circle that is on the arc of length $2\pi - \theta$ between $P$ and $Q$, (that is, "not between" $P$ and $Q$), then $\angle PRQ = \theta/2$.

(2) If a triangle has angles $A$, $B$, and $C$, and $a$ is the side opposite $A$, then the area of the triangle is $\frac{a^2 \sin B \sin C}{2\sin A}$.

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Comment: Your formula in (2) should be $\sin C$.

Comment: There is a typo in Fact 2. The area is $(1/2)ac\sin B$. And by the Sine Law we have $\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin C}{c}$, so $c=a\frac{\sin C}{\sin A}$, giving area $(1/2)a^2\frac{\sin B\sin C}{\sin A}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin : Thanks.  I fixed it.

Comment: @AndreNicolas : I had never seen this formula until today and I am surprised it is so easy to prove.

Comment: The basic structure shows exactly how to attack it. I don't know whether I had ever seen it. Perhaps. But one would certainly not bother to remember it: Mathematicians gather structural ideas, not formulas.

Comment: The basic structure shows exactly how to attack it. I don't know whether I had ever seen it. Perhaps. But one would certainly not bother to remember it: Mathematicians gather structural ideas, not formulas.

Comment: @JawuanSquadJackson : uh, your comment is exactly the same as Andre's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is simply "Angle at center is twice angle at circumference". This is easily shown by considering the isosceles triangles $OPQ, OQR, ORP$.

(2) follows from the area of a triangle being $\frac{1}{2} a b \sin C$, and the using the sine rule which states that $ \frac {a}{\sin A } = \frac {b} {\sin B}$, and substitute in $b = \frac {a \sin B} {\sin C} $.

Comment: For (1), $O$ can be inside, outside, or on the triangle $\Delta PQR$.  Do you have to consider different cases?

Comment: @StefanSmith Technically yes, and it's not that much harder.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Google "Inscribed Angle Theorem".

Comment: @Blue : Thanks.  Knowing the name of this theorem may make it easier to find a reference.

Comment: @StefanSmith: You should be able to find the Inscribed Angle Theorem in any geometry textbook ... going all the way back to Euclid. It is, literally, a classic result.

Comment: @Blue : yeah, when I get to the office tomorrow I'll crack open a trig book or two.

Comment: @CalvinLin : I did (1) by letting $P$ and $Q$ be $(\cos(\theta/2),\pm \sin(\theta/2))$ and $R = (\sin t, \cos t)$ with $\theta/2 < t < 2\pi - \theta/2$, using vectors and dot products.  This required only one case, but otherwise, your way appears more elegant.

Comment: @StefanSmith If you are comfortable with vectors, you can do the isosceles triangle proof using directed angles, which avoids the needs for cases. This is an extremely basic fact of circle geometry.

Comment: @CalvinLin : that would seem to be the easiest way.  I use vectors all the time, but I've never used directed angles in a trig or geometry arguement.